# Thunderbird addon to send one email to multiple recipients?

Tags: thunderbird, plugins

is there a thunderbird plugin/addon to send one email to more than one recipient without using cc or bcc and only to field.  I am not looking for a bulk mailer just something to help me email the same message to my employees without them knowing who I sent what to ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mail Merge for Thunderbird works great, unless you've updated to Thunderbird 11.0. The 'Personalize' function uses a contact list (address book) you create, ie 'Salesmen'. The message you type is sent as an individual email for each person on that list.

Worked great until Thunderbird updated to 11.0. BTW- it's considered 'deadware' now. Too bad.

Comment: If it's this add-on—https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/mail-merge/—it says it has been updated to work up to TB 13.*

Answer (score 1):

Open your address book, click the button `Add List`, enter the name of the recipients you want to mail to on the new window.

Add the list to bcc, done.

Comment: nop that way the person will know that he was not the main person, I want them to think they were the first on contact list.

Comment: fair enough, care for a script?

Comment: hmm why not, how do I go about it? I never did mozzilla, done Google chrome and etc but never mozzilla